# Laravel 8 Blade: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This issue is really doing my head in, so I'd appreciate any help I can get.
I don't know if the issue is my component or if I'm overlooking something really small and simple.

I am trying to conditionally show a column on my page, but for some reason using an @if @else @endif keeps throwing an error for unexpected end.

```
@if ($isCsr)
    <x-table.table :headers="[
        ['name' => 'Name', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Owner', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Company', 'align' => 'left'],
        'Status',
        'Created',
        'Requests',
        'Progress']"
    >
@else
    <x-table.table :headers="[
        ['name' => 'Name', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Owner', 'align' => 'left'],
        'Status',
        'Created',
        'Requests',
        'Progress']"
    >
@endif

@foreach($projects as $project)
    <x-table.tr-a link="{{ route('project.show',$project->id) }}">
        <x-table.td align="left">{{$project->name}}</x-table.td>
        <x-table.td align="left">{{$project->user->name}}</x-table.td>
        <x-table.td align="left">{{$project->company->name}}</x-table.td>
        <x-table.td>
            {{$project->status->name}}
        </x-table.td>
        <x-table.td>{{$project->created_at->format('M d, Y')}}</x-table.td>
        <x-table.td>{{$project->requests->count()}}</x-table.td>
        <x-table.td>
            @if($project->requests->count() > 0)
            {{number_format(($project->requestsClosed->count() / $project->requests->count()) * 100)}} %
            @else
            Not Started
            @endif
        </x-table.td>
    </x-table.tr>
@endforeach
</x-table.table>
```

I am trying to only show the Company column when $isCsr is true. There are no issues with the variable, nor passing it to the view. I can render it in the view and livewire filters work perfectly with the variable.

But as soon as I add the if-else-endif, it tells me there's an unexpected end. I've tried any number of combinations of if-else and even tried it in raw php. Still no luck.
There are no other if statements earlier in the file, there is one a little later in the file but it is closed off and has no problems. It's only when I add if-else-endif at this point in the file.

Comment: probably a good idea to add your component

Comment: look like you havent closed  x component .close x component so it works i guess

Comment: The component is closed later on (I'll add the full code now. The component works fine here and everywhere else, just not when adding this if statement

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? It should not be too hard to check this line by line to see which one causes the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like if else causing x component `$slot`.`@endif` goes to slot.
So better you can do this

```
@php 

$headers=$isCsr?[
        ['name' => 'Name', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Owner', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Company', 'align' => 'left'],
        'Status',
        'Created',
        'Requests',
        'Progress']:[
        ['name' => 'Name', 'align' => 'left'],
        ['name' => 'Owner', 'align' => 'left'],
        'Status',
        'Created',
        'Requests',
        'Progress'];
@endphp

    <x-table.table :headers="$headers">
```